# Camera is not working in one android app for Poco X3

Tags: java, android

// Camera activity code
public class CamActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback,
AspectRatioFragment.Listener {

```
public static boolean activityStatus;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
private static final String TAG = "CamActivity";

private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1;

private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

private static final int[] FLASH_OPTIONS = {
        CameraView.FLASH_AUTO,
        CameraView.FLASH_OFF,
        CameraView.FLASH_ON,
};

private static final int[] FLASH_ICONS = {
        R.drawable.ic_flash_auto,
        R.drawable.ic_flash_off,
        R.drawable.ic_flash_on,
};

private static final int[] FLASH_TITLES = {
        R.string.flash_auto,
        R.string.flash_off,
        R.string.flash_on,
};

private int mCurrentFlash;

private CameraView mCameraView;

private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
private FloatingActionButton fab;
private ImageView open_gallery;

private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.take_picture:
                if (mCameraView != null) {
                    try {
                        mCameraView.takePicture();
                        /*handler.postDelayed(() ->
                                mCameraView.takePicture(),
                                500);*/

                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.e(TAG,"mCameraView"+e.toString());
                    }
                }
                break;
            case R.id.open_gallery:
                openGallery();
                break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
    bundle1.putString(TAG, TAG);
    bundle1.putString(TAG, TAG);
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(TAG, bundle1);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_renderer);
    mCameraView = findViewById(R.id.camera);
    open_gallery = findViewById(R.id.open_gallery);
    if (open_gallery!=null)
        open_gallery.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    activityStatus = true;
    if (mCameraView != null) {
        mCameraView.addCallback(mCallback);
    }
     fab = findViewById(R.id.take_picture);
    if (fab != null) {
        fab.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    }
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }
    //toolbar.setTitle("Camera");
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back_arrow);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            closeCamera();
        }
    });
    //Listen for capture image and close camera
    registerReceiver(syncCamReceiver, new IntentFilter("Camera"));
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    closeCamera();

    super.onBackPressed();
}

/**CLose camera**/
private void closeCamera(){
    try{
        unregisterReceiver(syncCamReceiver);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG,"Error while unregistering");
    }
    SN88Constant.getIk6Obj(getApplicationContext()).sendPhotoSwitch(false);
    CamActivity.this.finish();

}

BroadcastReceiver syncCamReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("Camera")) {

            //0 for open cam, 1 take picture 2 close camera

            if(intent.getIntExtra(Constants.CAMERA_REQUEST_TYPE,-1)==1){

               fab .performClick();
            }
            else if(intent.getIntExtra(Constants.CAMERA_REQUEST_TYPE,-1)==2){

               CamActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    activityStatus = true;
    try {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (mCameraView != null)
                mCameraView.start();
        } else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            ConfirmationDialogFragment
                    .newInstance(R.string.camera_permission_confirmation,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                            REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION,
                            R.string.camera_permission_not_granted)
                    .show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG,"Camera_onresume"+e.toString());

    }
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mCameraView.stop();

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    closeCamera();
    activityStatus = false;
    if (mBackgroundHandler != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            mBackgroundHandler.getLooper().quitSafely();
        } else {
            mBackgroundHandler.getLooper().quit();
        }
        mBackgroundHandler = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
        @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION:
            if (permissions.length != 1 || grantResults.length != 1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error on requesting camera permission.");
            }
            if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.camera_permission_not_granted,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            // No need to start camera here; it is handled by onResume
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.aspect_ratio:
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            if (mCameraView != null
                    && fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_DIALOG) == null) {
                final Set<AspectRatio> ratios = mCameraView.getSupportedAspectRatios();
                final AspectRatio currentRatio = mCameraView.getAspectRatio();
                AspectRatioFragment.newInstance(ratios, currentRatio)
                        .show(fragmentManager, FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.switch_flash:
            if (mCameraView != null) {
                mCurrentFlash = (mCurrentFlash + 1) % FLASH_OPTIONS.length;
                item.setTitle(FLASH_TITLES[mCurrentFlash]);
                item.setIcon(FLASH_ICONS[mCurrentFlash]);
                mCameraView.setFlash(FLASH_OPTIONS[mCurrentFlash]);
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.switch_camera:
            if (mCameraView != null) {
                try {
                    int facing = mCameraView.getFacing();
                    mCameraView.setFacing(facing == CameraView.FACING_FRONT ?
                            CameraView.FACING_BACK : CameraView.FACING_FRONT);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onAspectRatioSelected(@NonNull AspectRatio ratio) {

    if (mCameraView != null) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, ratio.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            mCameraView.setAspectRatio(ratio);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG,"onAspectRatioSelected"+e.toString());
        }
    }
}

private Handler getBackgroundHandler() {
    if (mBackgroundHandler == null) {
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("background");
        thread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());
    }
    return mBackgroundHandler;
}

private CameraView.Callback mCallback
        = new CameraView.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onCameraOpened(CameraView cameraView) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCameraOpened");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraClosed(CameraView cameraView) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCameraClosed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(CameraView cameraView, final byte[] data) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken " + data.length);
        Toast.makeText(cameraView.getContext(), R.string.picture_taken, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        getBackgroundHandler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String folderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Camera";
                File folder = new File(folderPath);
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    File wallpaperDirectory = new File(folderPath);
                    wallpaperDirectory.mkdir();
                }

                File file = new File(folderPath,"/Img"+System.currentTimeMillis()+ ".png");

                OutputStream os = null;

                try {
                    os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    os.write(data);
                    os.close();
                    scanFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Cannot write to " + file, e);
                } finally {
                    if (os != null) {
                        try {
                            os.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // Ignore
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        });

    }

};

public static class ConfirmationDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String ARG_MESSAGE = "message";
    private static final String ARG_PERMISSIONS = "permissions";
    private static final String ARG_REQUEST_CODE = "request_code";
    private static final String ARG_NOT_GRANTED_MESSAGE = "not_granted_message";

    public static ConfirmationDialogFragment newInstance(@StringRes int message,
            String[] permissions, int requestCode, @StringRes int notGrantedMessage) {
        ConfirmationDialogFragment fragment = new ConfirmationDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_MESSAGE, message);
        args.putStringArray(ARG_PERMISSIONS, permissions);
        args.putInt(ARG_REQUEST_CODE, requestCode);
        args.putInt(ARG_NOT_GRANTED_MESSAGE, notGrantedMessage);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Bundle args = getArguments();
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setMessage(args.getInt(ARG_MESSAGE))
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                String[] permissions = args.getStringArray(ARG_PERMISSIONS);
                                if (permissions == null) {
                                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                                }
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                                        permissions, args.getInt(ARG_REQUEST_CODE));
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                        args.getInt(ARG_NOT_GRANTED_MESSAGE),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        })
                .create();
    }

}



//Scans the saved file so it appears in the gallery

private void scanFile(String path) {

    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
            new String[] { path }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("TAG", "Finished scanning " + path);
                }
            });
}

/*
* open gallery for image preview
* */
private void openGallery(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);

}
```

}
// Getting error :
E/CamActivity: mCameraViewjava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest$Builder.set(android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest$Key, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: Where is your code? Its a NPE . There are many solutions regarding this.

Comment: patch of code added

Comment: At which line it creates an issue?

Comment: in this  mCameraView.takePicture()

Comment: Does *activity_camera_renderer* contain _CameraPreview_ with id _camera_?

Comment: Yes. Camera is working fine with all other models excluding this POCO X3